# Django Assign Value To Model Form Before Validate

Tags: django, forms, validation

I prepared a Django Model Form for entering information by user.  I would like to made some of the fields, for example, the Document No., will automatically generated if user do not enter it.

However, in the view method, I cannot change the field content before it is validate.  The field in Model is mandatory so the Form.is_valid() will return False if the field leave blank.

So I would like to assign a value to the field before form validate but failed.  Now I need to assign the value into the form field before the entry form submit to the view method.

Is it possible to assign a value to Model Form before it validate?  I do not want to change the field to optional because it is the key field that I don't want it to leave blank accidentally.

Below is the example of my model and model form:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    doc_no = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    .
    .
    .

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model: Example
        fields: ['doc_no', ...]
        widgets = {
            'doc_no': forms.TextInput(attrs = {....}),
            .
            .
            .
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`class Example(models.Model):
    doc_no = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default='enter value here')`

This will set the default value to `default value here`, but the user's response, if any, will override the default value.

Does that help?